# Projection to plane definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

1. What is `||Proj of U to UxV ||` ? 
    no value given, so do i have to write a definition of projection? what kind of definition could be the best ? in HW
2. Find the vector, point normal and general forms of the equations of the plane passing through point `P:(1 0 -1)` and line `L:(x=1-2t, y=-1+t, z=1-2t)`. 
    thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Unless $U=\{0\}$, the norm of the projection $P:U\times V\to U,\ \ \langle u,v\rangle\mapsto u$ is always $1$. 
   ($\ \|u\|=\|P(u,v)\| \,\le\,\|(u,v)\|\overset{def}=\|u\|+\|v\|\ $ and $\ \|(u,0)\|=P(u,0)\|$ .)
2. Find two points on the line (e.g. with $t=0,1$), then a normal of the plain will be obtained by cross product of any two vector formed by the $3$ given points.